# 404 Not Found in yii framework

Tags: php, yii

I'm new user of yii framework. I've got project and its name is `crm` now when I try to run it, it gives me the error of `404 Not Found` and below of it shows `The requested URL /crm/web/index.php was not found on this server.`, now when I go to my root index.php it has following line `<?php header('Location: /crm/web/index.php'); ?>` and when I just go into `web/index.php` it has a lot of code now the problem is it can't access/find the index.php in web directory I also tried and create another file `testing.php` and change `<?php header('Location: /livecrm/web/index.php'); ?>` to `<?php header('Location: /livecrm/web/testing.php'); ?>` but it didn't work for me I already set the `Environment Variables`, so now what to do.

[image]

Thanks in advanced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Yii2 and have several application inside your project .. from your explorer i see

your project is named  livecrm

inside you  have thiese application dir

- frontend
- livecrm
- liveCRMV2.2
- livefactory

and other

then what you named `"I've got project and its name is crm"` is not present

but done your app dir structure if you want execute a webapp inside your project you should use (eg for webapp frontend)

```
livecrm/frontend/web/index.php
```

or for livecrm

```
livecrm/livecrm/web/index.php
```

Comment: And then work?.. problem? error ? Explain better.. whar's happened

Comment: its working now and now I'm removing database errors... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make sure there is index.php file in path crm/web/index.php

Put this line to your root index.php file.

instead of your header location:

```
<?php
$host  = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$uri   = rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '/\\');
$extra = '/web/index.php';
header("Location: http://$host$uri/$extra");
?>
```

and also check your .htaccess file.

It should be:-

```
Options -Multiviews
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /crm/

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . web/index.php
```

Comment: Which version of Yii you are using?

Comment: I got project and want to configure but I can't and that's why I also can't check the version because project is not working...

Comment: Is there any file where I can check version instead of this `echo Yii::getVersion();` function.

Comment: `.htaccess` code is for root `.htaccess` file or for web's `.htaccess` file.

Comment: its giving `Internal Server Error` now.

Comment: `Internal Server Error`

Comment: `The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.`

Comment: `Please contact the server administrator at admin@example.com to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.`

Comment: `More information about this error may be available in the server error log.`

Comment: Sorry Bro :( Without seeing your code, It is very difficult to tell you any suggestion.

Comment: you can check Yii version in your root index.php file after  $yii and $config line.

Comment: Your landing file should be at protected/view/site or under crm/themes folder

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99460/discussion-between-user3833682-and-ravi-hirani).